# How to deal with slow image analysis (pyQT / OpenCV / Python)

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, opencv, pyqt5

I want to create a program that show an image from a webcam, read the text, compare it with a predefined structure and pause when the structure matches. I'm quite new, so I learn a lot with this project.

I've created my GUI with pyQT and converted with pyUIC. Then I create a class VideoThread(QThread) to get images from my webcam, and a class MyWindow(QMainWindow) to show the GUI and deal with the actions buttons (start, stop...)

I've created a function that recognise the text but is quite slow (~300ms). If I apply it on each frame of the Thread it gradually shifts from the "real time" image.
So I don't want to analyse each frame, but run my function with the actual frame, and at the end of the function start again with the actual frame...which can be 2 or 3 frames after. But I don't know how to deal with this function. Should it be in a Class? in another Thread? How to give it access to the current frame?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal, Qt
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QCameraInfo
import cv2
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
import numpy as np
import skimage.exposure
from fct_mod import analyser

from Process import Ui_MainWindow

class VideoThread(QThread):
    change_pixmap_signal = pyqtSignal(np.ndarray)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        # capture from webcam
        self._run_flag = True
        self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
        while self._run_flag:
            ret, cv_img = self.cap.read()
            if ret:
                self.change_pixmap_signal.emit(cv_img)
        # shut down capture system
        self.cap.release()

    def stop(self):
        """Sets run flag to False and waits for thread to finish"""
        self._run_flag = False

class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.available_cameras = QCameraInfo.availableCameras()  # Getting available cameras

        self.m_ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.m_ui.setupUi(self)

        self.max_expo = 192
        self.initWindow()
        self.cv_img = None

    ########################################################################################################################
    #                                                   Windows                                                            #
    ########################################################################################################################
    def initWindow(self):
        # create the video capture thread
        self.thread = VideoThread()

        # Button to start video
        self.m_ui.lbl_image.setText("Cliquer sur Démarrer")
        self.m_ui.bt_continuer.setText("Démarrer")

        self.m_ui.bt_continuer.clicked.connect(self.ClickStartVideo)

        self.m_ui.sliderL.setProperty("value", 192)
        self.m_ui.statusbar.showMessage('Ready to start')


    ########################################################################################################################
    #                                                   Buttons                                                            #
    ########################################################################################################################
    # Activates when Start/Stop video button is clicked to Start (ss_video
    def ClickStartVideo(self):
        # Change label color to light blue
        self.m_ui.bt_continuer.clicked.disconnect(self.ClickStartVideo)
        self.m_ui.statusbar.showMessage('Video Running...')
        # Change button to stop
        self.m_ui.bt_continuer.setText('Pause')
        self.thread = VideoThread()
        self.thread.change_pixmap_signal.connect(self.update_image)

        # start the thread
        self.thread.start()
        self.m_ui.bt_continuer.clicked.connect(self.thread.stop)  # Stop the video if button clicked
        self.m_ui.bt_continuer.clicked.connect(self.ClickStopVideo)

        # Disconnect updating image when slider is changed.
        if self.cv_img is not None:
            self.m_ui.sliderL.valueChanged.disconnect(self.update_image_when_video_paused)

    # Activates when Start/Stop video button is clicked to Stop (ss_video)
    def ClickStopVideo(self):
        self.thread.change_pixmap_signal.disconnect()
        self.m_ui.bt_continuer.setText('Démarrer')
        self.m_ui.statusbar.showMessage('Ready to start')
        self.m_ui.bt_continuer.clicked.disconnect(self.ClickStopVideo)
        self.m_ui.bt_continuer.clicked.disconnect(self.thread.stop)
        self.m_ui.bt_continuer.clicked.connect(self.ClickStartVideo)

        # Connect the slider signal to update image
        self.m_ui.sliderL.valueChanged.connect(self.update_image_when_video_paused)

    ########################################################################################################################
    #                                                   Actions                                                            #
    ########################################################################################################################

    def render_processed_image(self, cv_img, min_expo=50, max_expo=255):
        if min_expo != 50:
            print(min_expo)
        if max_expo != self.max_expo:
            print(f"max_expo changed to {max_expo}")
            self.max_expo = max_expo
        img_expo = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(cv_img, in_range=(min_expo, max_expo),
                                                      out_range=(0, 255)).astype(np.uint8)
        img_analyse, text_analyse = analyser(img_expo) #that is too long for each frame
        qt_img = self.convert_cv_qt(img_expo)
        self.m_ui.lbl_image.setPixmap(qt_img)
        qt_imgOCR = self.convert_cv_qt(img_analyse)
        self.m_ui.lbl_image.setPixmap(qt_imgOCR)

    def update_image(self, cv_img):
        """Updates the image_label with a new opencv image"""
        self.cv_img = cv_img
        self.render_processed_image(self.cv_img, max_expo=self.m_ui.sliderL.value())

    def update_image_when_video_paused(self):
        self.render_processed_image(self.cv_img, max_expo=self.m_ui.sliderL.value())

    def convert_cv_qt(self, cv_img):
        """Convert from an opencv image to QPixmap"""
        rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(cv_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        h, w, ch = rgb_image.shape
        bytes_per_line = ch * w
        convert_to_Qt_format = QtGui.QImage(rgb_image.data, w, h, bytes_per_line, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
        p = convert_to_Qt_format.scaled(int(self.m_ui.centralwidget.width() / 2),
                                        int(self.m_ui.centralwidget.width() / 2),
                                        Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        return QPixmap.fromImage(p)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MyWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Obviously, the processing cannot be done in the main thread, and it should be done in a separate thread that will eventually emit a custom signal as soon as it's able to process the data. A possibility could be to create a further QThread with a lock, a function in it that is directly called from the main thread to set the "new" image **only** if the lock is not `locked()`, a continuous `run()` function that will set the lock to get the current image (and copy its data) if it's different from the previously processed one, and eventually emit a signal about the processed results.

Comment: Unfortunately, the above implementation is a bit difficult to achieve, and I really cannot write an answer on that. I strongly suggest you to take your time to understand and try to implement the above. In the meantime, also try to improve your code styling, as it's completely inconsistent: you have `snake_case`, `mixedCase`, `CamelCase` (also used for function names, which is a bad practice) all together, not to mention cryptic names (`m_ui`) or inconsistent underscore prefixes; all that makes your code difficult (and annoying) to read, understand or debug. And even to you.

Comment: It's unspecific. See [ask]. Research more, implement a prototype, and ask a specific question with a [mre]. Here is a hint. A worker thread for recognition runs an event loop. The main thread signals the worker with a recently captured image. The worker signals the main thread when it finishes a recognition task. The main thread signals the worker again with a new image.